# node_modules not mounted in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

I have dockerized a php application which require some npm dependencies, so I've installed in the Docker container `nodejs` and the required packages using:

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apk add icu-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl

RUN apk add --update libzip-dev curl-dev &&\
    docker-php-ext-install curl && \
    apk del gcc g++ &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY docker/php-fpm/config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
RUN npm install gulp-cli -g
RUN npm install

COPY src src/

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

version: '3.7'

```
services:
  php-fpm:
    container_name: boilerplate_app
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
```

the problem's that when I enter in the container using: `docker exec -ti boilerplate_app sh`

and launch that command: `ls -la` I can't see any `node_modules` folder, infact, if I try to execute the installed dependency `gulp` I get:

> Local modules not found in /var/www/html
> Try running: npm install

What I did wrong?

Comment: The `volumes:` hide everything that the image built in `/var/www/html` and replace it with content from your host system.  If you delete this block from your `docker-compose.yml` file then your container will run the code that's built into the image (including the `npm install`ed Node modules).

Comment: if I remove the `volumes:` everything is inserted in `src` folder and also the `node_modules` doesn't exists in that folder. @DavidMaze

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. You are running `npm install` in a folder that does not contain any `package.json` listing the required node modules to install. If you inspect the logs you should see something like

```
no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/package.json'
```

2. Moreover, when you mount your local `src` folder, you are replacing the content of `/var/www/html/` with `src` content, which might not include any `node_modules` folder

```
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
```

Comment: if I remove the volumes: everything is inserted in src folder and also the node_modules doesn't exists in that folder